# js timeout best practice

Tags: javascript

Basiaclly I need to set a time out to run 2 functions at two different times and wanted to strucuture it right. What I was looking for is something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').chardinJs('start');
    },3000
  );
setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').chardinJs('stop');
    },6000
  );
```

So it would run one method after 3sec and another after 6sec. Is this correct way or can you chain them together?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Your solution works fine... There is one thing to consider though... do you want stop to happen 3 seconds after start?  If that is the case, it would be better to kick off the stop timeout after that start has happened.

Comment: Nothing, it works. Just was seeing if there was a cleaner way to chain them together. If this is the best way, then I will keep it

Answer (score 0):

This is correct.

However you should have a look on Javascript callbacks or [jQuery deferred handlers](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/). Could be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

```
function sto(el, str, tm){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(el).chardinJs(str);
    },tm
  );
}
sto('body', 'start', 3000);
sto('body', 'stop', 6000);
```

> another would be so much longer (`setInterval, [switch] or [if]`)